# Excel VBA delete ExternalData_* Range Names

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few connections that grabs data from the Internet to my Excel file.
Each time the data is copied to the file, I get a range name like:

```
ExternalData_1
ExternalData_2
...
```

I'm trying to delete these range names before running the queries with:

```
Dim nName As Name 

For Each nName In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
   If nName.Name Like "ExternalData*" Then nName.Delete 
Next nName
```

But this isn't deleting any of the names, why?

Comment: Check the sheet names too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub test()
    Dim nName As Name

    For Each nName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
       If Left(nName.Name, 12) = "ExternalData" Then nName.Delete
    Next nName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The Name(s) might start with the worksheet name, so you may have to change the  code like so

```
If Left(nName.Name, 19) = "Sheet1!ExternalData" Then nName.Delete
```